# TFLearn pip installation bug

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've tried installing tflearn through pip as follows

`pip install tflearn`

and now when I open python, the following happens:

`>>> import tflearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/activations.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import initializations
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/initializations.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.initializers import \
ImportError: cannot import name variance_scaling_initializer`

Any ideas? I'm using an anaconda installation of python.

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions](http://tflearn.org/installation/) ? Do you have installed TensorFlow and does it work?

Comment: I am also having this error.  I have a working version of tensorflow 0.8.0rc0 installed.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the error you get when trying to import tensorflow

Comment: Upgrading tensorflow to 0.9.0rc0 fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `variance_scaling_initializer()` function was [added on April 19th](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/eca3854bc5e4e7d8fa4db9f487c78ccac37b6c23), which means that it wasn't included in version 0.8.0rc0, and you need to upgrade to a newer version of TensorFlow. If you upgrade to the 0.9.0rc0 version that was released this week, tflearn should work.

Answer (score 0):

Last tflearn update had a compatibility issue with old TensorFlow versions (like mrry said, caused by 'variance_scaling_initializer()' that was only compatible with TensorFlow 0.9).
That error had already been fix, so you can just update TFLearn and it should works fine with any TensorFlow version over 0.7.

Comment: i am getting the following error..
ImportError: No module named framework.python.ops

Answer (score 0):

This is because your TensorFlow version is too low. Tflearn requires tensorflow‘s version >= 1.0, so you should reinstall tensorflow again， and reinstall step like this：

```
For python2.7:
sudo pip install tensorflow==1.0   #cpu version
sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0 # gpu version

For python3:
sudo pip3 install tensorflow==1.0   #cpu version
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.0 # gpu version
```